# How to do you insert new line character ie "↵" as a character (ASCII VALUE 10) in a javascript string without breaking it into a new line?

Tags: javascript, string, ascii, special-characters

I am writing a string into a file that uses '↵' character explicity. However upon writing into a file the file reads it as an indicator to begin a new line how do i tackle this?

I am making a huffman encoder. the format of the encoded text is-
Line 1- huffman tree in a preorder format eg- "00^a1^b10^↵^1c where ^ indicates the leaf node.
Line 2- contains an integer which is essentially padding to be removed in the decoding phase
Line 3- is the actual text to be decoded.

Now the issue i am facing is that is the decoding phase, when i am splitting the entire text using new line to get tree, padding and actual string to be decoded, i should get 3 things separately. However when splitting with('\n') my stringfied representation of the tree is also getting split making parsing impossible.

An example
**1)String to be encoded-**

> Hello.
> This is a trial text.
> Hello World!

**2)Binary Mapping of each char is string**
"↵": "0000"
" ": "100"
!: "00010"
.: "0100"
H: "0110"
T: "00110"
W: "01010"
a: "11111"
d: "01011"
e: "1011"
h: "00111"
i: "1010"
l: "110"
o: "1110"
r: "0010"
s: "11110"
t: "0111"
x: "00011"
**proto**: Object

**3) Encoded text-**

> 0000^
> 10^!1^x10^r10^T1^h100^.10^W1^d10^H1^t100^ 10^i1^e10^l10^o10^s1^a
> 5
> kÛzô¯OÇ*þct½º+,@

notice the line break after "0000^" if it can be "0000^↵" then my problem would be solved

Comment: Can you show some example code with the strings? I posted an answer but I'm not entirely sure if it will fit your needs. ASCII code 10 is `A` in hexadecimal, have you tried splitting on `\x0A` or `\u000A`?

Comment: Can the text in line 3 contain any newlines? If so, you could try to only split on the last two newlines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that `"\n"` has the ASCII value of 10.

Therefore your string actually looks like this:

```
00^a1^b10^(ASCII_VALUE_10)^1c(ASCII_VALUE_10)(INTEGER)(ASCII_VALUE_10)Text to be encoded
```

Or more conventionally it is usually displayed as the following as you have discovered:

```
00^a1^b10^
^1c
(INTEGER)
Text to be encoded
```

You want to use ASCII VALUE 10 as both a value in the first line and the line delimiter ("\n"). This is a contradiction in logic as well as a contradiction in the English language.

But all is not lost. What you have created is just a data format encoded in 4 lines instead of 3

Comment: when parsing the stringified tree which is now in two lines how do i identify the new line character now

Comment: as completeString.split('\n') will return an array of 4 strings sans the '\n' character

Comment: in decoding ie.

Comment: If newlines are an important part of data you need to implement an escape mechanism. It is this reason people have invented various mechanisms to encode a newline (ASCII 10/0x0a). For example the C programming language encodes it as `\n` because of this `\` has special meaning in C so to represent itself it needs to escape itself: `\\`. HTTP invented `%0A` to encode newlines (ASCII 10 or 0x0a) in URLs because newlines are used to delimit HTTP header fields. HTML encodes a line break as `<br>` because they want actual newlines (ASCII 10) to be ignored in code

Comment: .. you can invent your own encoding or steal from something well established. Say you follow the C convention. So you should encode it as `\n0000^ 100 ...` etc. And when you need to encode `\` you do `\\1100^ ...` etc.

Comment: .. This is an old problem with well established and old solutions. Google "byte stuffing" and "escape character" - both are basically the concept I described above but one is used more in binary protocols and the other in text based protocols

Comment: .. the other solution is don't invent your own data format. Because from this problem it is clear that you don't have much experience with data formats. Instead use a well-established format such as ASN.1 or Bencoding